# Dynamically scheduling tasks in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails app that downloads some JSON from an API. This JSON contains a series of times. At each of these times, I have to run a controller action that needs to update my database.
What is the best way to schedule this? I know about rake tasks and the 'Whenever' gem, but is there a way to dynamically schedule new tasks from the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to run these updates through a browser? Generally you would want those kinds of things to be at the model level, leaving the controller exclusively to handle the HTTP traffic. The old fat model, skinny controller idea. If you did move the logic to the model, you could use crontabs and rake tasks to make that work.

If you ABSOLUTELY have to do it through the browser, I would recommend using [Watir](http://watir.com/) combined with [headless](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless) to write a custom script that would click around for you.